# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Tags: python-3.x

Installed python-3.6.5-embed-amd64.zip in windows7(no rights to execute exe file).
It has no pip, so installed pip by running get-pip.py and it downloaded Lib and Scripts folder. But still when i run pip or pip3 in command prompt i am still getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`.
I am setting PATH in command prompt for PYTHON,scripts and Lib folder.
`PATH=%PATH%;Python folder`
Help us to understand the issue.

Detailed error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "runpy.py", line 193, in run_module_as_main File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code File "c:\Users\1561024\Raja\softwares\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\Scripts\pip.exe __main_.py", line 5, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
  File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
  File "c:\Users\1561024\Raja\softwares\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\Scripts\pip.exe
\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

Comment: did you give complete path of the scripts folder to your PATH variable.

Comment: Yes, i have given upto scripts, in scripts i have all pip related .exe files. pip command is executed (not from script folder) so it is set correctly.

Comment: OK as a point of interest try `python -m pip`

Comment: Hi Simon,c:\Users\1561024\Raja\softwares\python-3.6.5-embed-amd64\python.exe: No module n
amed pip

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install <whatever you need here>
```

without the arrow brackets

Comment: Also make sure you installed pip for python 3.6 and not an older version of Python

Comment: py is not recognized as internal or external command. I don't find py.exe.

Comment: As i installed by running using get-pip.py it should have installed latest only. I ddin't save the logs of the version. If i try to run now to check the version(pip -version) getting the same error.

Comment: Yes i tried pip uninstall and install. And also tried python 3.6.5 and 3.6.4, both have same issue.

Comment: Yes installed on C drive, i don't understand why you have this question

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, are you able to install on the root of C:?